# Encountered error during federation passive request.

Tags: active-directory, saml, adfs2.0, adfs, saml-2.0

I am trying to setup ADFS to work with SAML 2.0 Service Provider, but I am facing an issue that can't authenticate users via ADFS webpage. This is the error I am getting:

```
Encountered error during federation passive request. 

Additional Data 

Exception details: 
Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.RequestFailedException: MSIS7012: An error occurred while processing the request. Contact your administrator for details. ---> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustClientManager.Issue(Message request, WCFResponseData responseData)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustClient.Issue(RequestSecurityToken rst, WCFResponseData responseData)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.FederationPassiveAuthentication.SubmitRequest(MSISRequestSecurityToken request)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.FederationPassiveAuthentication.SubmitRequest(MSISRequestSecurityToken request)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.FederationPassiveAuthentication.RequestBearerToken(MSISSignInRequestMessage signInRequest, SecurityTokenElement onBehalfOf, SecurityToken primaryAuthToken, String desiredTokenType, Uri& replyTo)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.FederationPassiveAuthentication.BuildSignInResponseCoreWithSecurityToken(SecurityToken securityToken, WSFederationMessage incomingMessage)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.FederationPassiveAuthentication.BuildSignInResponseForProtocolRequest(FederationPassiveContext federationPassiveContext, SecurityToken securityToken)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.FederationPassiveAuthentication.BuildSignInResponse(SecurityToken securityToken)

System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustClientManager.Issue(Message request, WCFResponseData responseData)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustClient.Issue(RequestSecurityToken rst, WCFResponseData responseData)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.FederationPassiveAuthentication.SubmitRequest(MSISRequestSecurityToken request)
```

Any ideas what it could be? I tried many setting options, even reinstalled ADFS on the fresh windows copy.

Comment: Have you fixed this issue?  Please share if yes .Same error for me .